# How to install zend framework 2 on wamp server ? Its installing 3.02 beta version

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, installation, composer-php

I want to install zend framework 2 on wamp server windows 8.1

I have already downloaded skeleton of zend framework and put it in www directory with composer as well

I have Followed below links to install the zf2

---

http://www.w3programmers.com/install-zend-framework-2-on-your-wamp-and-xampp-server/

http://www.stepblogging.com/how-to-install-zend-framework-2-on-wamp/

But when i run the **composer install** command **It  install 3.0.2 dev version** . I want to install zend framework 2.

**Note : Composer is installed , its working fine. Environment Varriable is set. Just issue with version. Composer is installing version 3.0.2 instead of 2**

Hope its clear

Your help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you download the framework as described in both tutorials, you should select the version you want.

## solution 1: download zip

You can select the version you want from the [release page](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/releases): for instance the current latest [v2.5.0](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/archive/release-2.5.0.zip)

## solution 2: using git

As per the tutorial, you have to clone the repository: `git clone git://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication.git`.

Once this is done, rather than doing step 7, get into the folder and switch to the tag you want to use: `git checkout release-2.5.0`.

---

In both cases you end up with the same version, and then you can run `composer install` to fetch the dependencies, just as in the tutorials.

**On another note, and as Quentin stated, you should start with ZF3 straight away, it is not very different. Also, you should probably stick to the official documentation at first rather than outdated tutorials.**

Comment: is this zfc user module supporting in zend framework 3 ? - https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser

Comment: No it's not unfortunately

Comment: Thanks works like charms !!! installed zend framework 2 from link you have given and zfc user as well its working . Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

#### Using Composer to install Zend Framework 2

Assuming `composer` is [installed][1] on the target box.

To install a skeleton MVC application, run in your terminal to create a new zend framework 2 project in specified location:

```
php composer.phar create-project -sdev \
    --repository-url="https://packages.zendframework.com" \
    zendframework/skeleton-application path/to/install
```

to manually install a **minimal** ZF2 (Zend MVC + its handful of dependencies), run in your command line:

```
composer require zendframework/zend-mvc
```

or for a **full-fledge**d ZF2 (+64 modules):

```
composer require zendframework/zendframework`
```

Please note that the first option runs an installer that will provide you with a fully-functionnal application along with the usual application directories structure. Other options will let you build the whole application from scratch as it simply provides ZF2 modules to build upon.

---

Oh, and there's no (much) difference between ZF2 and ZF3... Actually, it is said to be ZF3 because the MVC module went to version 3 recently, but there's still lots of module on version 2... So I don't see where's the problem with using ZF2, it's quite the same, with only minor backward compatibility problems as it is an evolution of ZF2, not a new framework (as it was the case for ZF1 to ZF2).
Since Zend-MVC is the "heart" of the framework, the skeleton version simply follows it.

> > Excerpted from [Getting started with zend-framework2 - Installation or Setup](https://web.archive.org/web/20171006223531/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/zend-framework2/1304/getting-started-with-zend-framework2/4270/installation-or-setup#t=201710062235316593552). The original authors were [Sanjeev kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5164379/sanjeev-kumar), [Shirraz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4593653/shirraz) and [edigu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/199593/edigu). Attribution details can be found on the [contributor page](https://web.archive.org/web/2/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/example/4270). The source is licenced under [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) and may be found in the [Documentation archive](https://archive.org/details/documentation-dump.7z). Reference topic ID: 1304 and example ID: 4270.

Comment: is this zfc user module supporting in zend framework 3 ? - https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser

Comment: This guy seems to have updated ZfcUser himself for ZF3... Not sure it works as intended, but it's worth checking it out. Wouldn't specifying the version in the `composer.json` work either ?

That said, I don't know what's your goal, but deploying a skeleton while trying to use a module that is not much actively maintained / compatible with the current version of the same skeleton quite strange... :P

Comment: No worries , got your point ,upvoted your answer as well its help me a lot .Thank you so much :)

Comment: Ok ;) Didn't mean to be like "why the hell do you want to do A, just go B no matter it's not what you need / you're asking for" as some people say all the time, but for once it looked appropriate to stir you away from your base plan... :P ty !